# Collection prefactors of arbitrary functions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, term-rewriting

I generated a very lengthy expression in Mathematica which can be written in the form $f(x,y,z)\log(x-y+z) + g(x,y,z)\log(x+y+z) + h(x,y)\log(x+y-z)$ etc. I would like to collect the functions $f(x,y,z)$ etc.
I know that `Collect` does this for polynomials. My question is if there is a function/routine which generalizes this to, e.g. in this case, logarithms.

Comment: `List @@ (f[x, y, z] Log[3 x - 2] + g[x, y, z] Log[3 x - 2]) /. 
 Times[a_, Log[__]] :> a` returns `{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z]}`

Comment: Maybe using `/.` to replace $f(x,y,z)$with a symbol `f`, then feed it into `Collect[]` with respect to `f`.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want. Are you combining terms that have the same $f$, and then putting the logarithms together using log rules? Or do you want to collect all terms with the same logarithm expression? Please edit your post by including a sample input and sample output, properly formatted in copy-and-paste-able *Mathematica* code. (For the latter, you should be able to use something like `Collect[expr, Log[_]]`.)

Comment: @Funzies. Have I answered your question? Please let me know if it doesn't satisfy or if it doesn't match your description (I was a bit confused by your description).

Comment: Look, I hope you did not get offended by my comments. My point is that the code you posted, *as written*, is not correct.  Of course that is because it wasn't meant to be complete, just an illustration.  But by making it just a rough illustration of the real code, you are hiding critical details which may have a huge impact on performance.  For example, in the example where you say that the determinant is calculated once symbolically, it is *probably* in fact recalculated *symbolically* for every single evaluation, which will be very slow.

Comment: But it's hard to tell what is going on wihtout the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the expression

```
expr1 = f[x, y, z] Log[x + y - z] + g[x, y, z] Log[x + y - z] + h[x, y, z] Log[x + y + z];
```

First, we `Collect` terms with the same `Log` expression:

```
expr2 = Collect[expr1, _Log]
(* (f[x, y, z] + g[x, y, z]) Log[x + y - z] + h[x, y, z] Log[x + y + z] *)
```

At this point, there are a couple of options. Here's one:

```
expr3 = List @@@ List @@ expr2
(* {{f[x, y, z] + g[x, y, z], Log[x + y - z]}, {h[x, y, z], Log[x + y + z]}} *)
```

and if you only want the functions:

```
expr3[[All,1]]
(* {f[x, y, z] + g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]} *)
```

Alternatively, extract the coefficients using `CoefficientList`:

```
expr3 = Module[{i = 0, x}, 
  CoefficientList[expr2 /. Log[__] :> x[i++], Reverse@Array[x, i, 0]]
 ]
(* {{0, f[x, y, z] + g[x, y, z]}, {h[x, y, z], 0}} *)
```

Then, we can do

```
DeleteCases[Flatten@expr3, 0]
(* {f[x, y, z] + g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]} *)
```

Comment: The problem I am having is slightly different. My length expression is of the form "f(x)*log(ax + b) + g(x)*log(cx+d) + ... + z(x)*log(ax+b)" so the point is that I want to collect all the terms that multiply the logarithm log(ax+b). Mathematica does not do this automatically. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Funzies. I don't really understand, because based on your description in the OP and in your comment above, it sounds to me like I've done what you want. Can you add one or two sample expressions and the wanted output format? When you say "collect", do you mean that you want the output in the format that `Collect` would normally output? Because if so, that's one step along the way in my answer above.

Comment: Excuse me, I was to quick in answering. In fact, you did answer my question completely. Thank you very much!